# eclipse plugin for domain object mapping generator

Tags: java

Is there an eclipse plugin that helps generate mapping code between 2 domain objects. For example I have:

```
Class A { 
String name;
.. getter & setter
}

class B {
String name;
.. getter & setter
}
```

Eclipse plugin will generate

```
map(A a, B b)
{
a.setName(b.getName())
}
```

I want the mapping to be explicit so I know for sure what fields will be mapped at runtime. Also if I don't have to use reflection, it will be great.

Thanks,

Sean